# How do I add a loop cut to sphere around its pole?

Tags: modeling, loop

I am trying to model human eye. I am following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/WvDqL4npUVI?t=300). My current design looks like this:

[image: My Current Design]

At this point, I need to create the pupil of the eye. But even the closest loop to the center of the eye is too large. I want to add one or two smaller loops in order to keep the pupil small.

The problem is, I can add loop cuts anywhere on the sphere, but I can't add a loop cut around the pole.

Adding loop cuts away from the pole is possible:
[image: Adding loop cut away from the pole]

But adding loop cut around the pole is not possible. I just tries to add new vertexes on the single edges:
[image: Adding loop cut near the pole]

I tried adding single vertexes one by one by using Ctrl+R, then selecting every adjacent two vertexes one by one and connecting them with edges by using the F shortcut key. But this method didn't create separate faces on the sphere.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inset, select all these vertices and press <kbd>i</kbd>:

[image]

You could also slightly bevel the edge loop and scale or slide the inner one:

[image]

You also have *Offset Edge Slide* <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>:

[image]

As Jakemoyo suggests, you can also create a bevel on the central vertex: Select it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> then <kbd>V</kbd> to switch to vertex bevel:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I swear I tried insetting, but I didn't select the pole vertex, so it didn't work when I first tried. The pole vertex must be selected for this method to work.

Comment: you could also slightly bevel the edge loop and scale the inner one

Comment: I would recommend using Ctrl+Shift+B (or Ctrl+B, V) to bevel the top vertex to create the edge loop. Rather than slightly beveling the final loop, that can cause distortion and loss of the "perfect" state of the sphere.

Comment: @Jakemoyo, yes but it creates a ngon so I guess it depends on what he wants

Comment: @moonboots Well, everything is triangles under the hood, and turns to quads when you add a subdiv modifier. "If it looks good, it is good" is my motto.

Comment: @Jakemoyo, sure, I've edited my answer, I also forgot the Offset Edge Slide

Comment: In blender there's always 9 ways to do everything, that's why we love it.